# Select part from the values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have such problem/question. I am trying to extract data from database, but only part. The real example is:

```
{ 
   "email":"bla@gmail.com",
   "addinfo":{ 
      "invoice_id":"1F5FspmpyfQ"
   },
   "cardholder":"blabla",
   "masked_pan":"123456XXXXXX1234"
}
```

I need to receive only `1F5FspmpyfQ`, all between `{"invoice_id": " and "}`,.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html use a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Postgres' [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
select the_column::jsonb -> 'addinfo' ->> 'invoice_id' as invoice_id
from the_table;
```

`->` returns a json object with the specified key and `->>` returns the key's value as a text (rather than `jsonb`)

Comment: thank you! It works:

select * from 
( select *, params::jsonb -> 'addinfo' ->>  'invoice_id' as invoice_id from the_table)as foo

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON functions in SQL Server, but JSON support was not introduced until SQL Server 2016:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{
   "email":"blablabla",
   "addinfo":{
      "invoice_id":"1F5FspmpyfQ"
   },
   "cardholder":"bla bla",
   "masked_pan":"12345XXXXXX1234"
}';
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.addinfo.invoice_id');
```

Comment: The question is for Postgres, not SQL Server (and the [tag:sql] tag does **not** refer to SQL Server, but to standard SQL)